# How is the [reduction] tag supposed to be used?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) tag has no usage guidance.

It seems to be used for pretty much anything that could be called "reduction", from compression of data to simplification of a formula.

Is this acceptable?

If not, what should we do about it?

Comment: My first intuition was that it should be used in the meaning of "fold", "aggregate" or "scan", but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction#Computing_and_algorithms , it may have (too?) many meanings.

Comment: Maybe it needs burnination, and we need to make tags for every meaning of it that is on-topic.

Comment: Why would somebody down-vote this‽

Comment: Users tag questions as they see fit. That by itself is acceptable.

Comment: If you want speculation about the down vote: Maybe it is too broad to be properly discussed and your question is lacking any suggestion that can be actioned.

Comment: This tag should be removed.

Comment: Agreed. It is ambiguous. Should be removed

Comment: 1. Edit this into a [burnination request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) 2. Suggested title: A [reduction] in staff is needed

Comment: @Machavity not "A [reduction] in bad tags is needed"?