# Disambiguate the [reduction] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

As [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386262/how-is-the-reduction-tag-supposed-to-be-used) mentions, the [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) tag has no usage guidance and as can be seen from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction#Computing_and_algorithms), has several meanings in the context of "Computing and algorithms". It seems to be used on multiple different kinds of questions:

1. [Reduction](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Reduce) in the sense of reducing an array under an operation. Skimming random pages of questions tagged with [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction), the majority of questions tagged [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) seem to be using this meaning, but perhaps they could just use [fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fold) instead (however, they're not the same thing, as [Cimbali's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408215) points out). [reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers), which Bergi pointed out, also means basically the same thing.
2. [Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)) in the sense of transforming one problem into another. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64738321/np-complete-problems-to-partition-problem-reductions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170888/are-lower-bounds-established-by-reductions-tight) are two examples.
3. [Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction) from lambda calculus - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63151770/lambda-reduction) is an example.
4. Reduction in the sense of compressing something - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335525/lookup-table-size-reduction) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085886/css-reduction-tool) are examples. In this specific case, the [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) tag could perhaps be removed entirely in favor of the [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) tag.
5. Reduction functions in the context of rainbow tables - [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353139/java-convert-hash-to-random-string) is an example.
6. Reduction in the sense of making code shorter/simpler - [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299025/can-i-reduce-this-javascript-code), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477833/reducing-a-boolean-expression) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085886/css-reduction-tool) are examples. These are the only three questions I found, though, and the first, at least, can be edited to remove the [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) tag (I tried removing it, but my edit wouldn't go through because of the title).

---

I've probably missed a couple. Since this tag is ambiguous, I feel that separate tags should be made for each general meaning of "reduction". [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) doesn't really meet the burnination criteria, but it's ambiguity is probably enough of a problem.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

I think so. For APL questions involving the reduce operator (`/`), it definitely describes the question. I assume this is true for most questions. In each context, the meaning of "reduction" is more or less unambiguous - I don't think there's too much overlap in the categories listed above.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Definitely. The different meanings mentioned above and on Wikipedia appear to be on-topic.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I think it does. For a [complexity-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory) question, it lets the reader know that the question's possibly about simplifying a problem, and not say, [function problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Function_problems).

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, it does not.

---

How should this be handled? Should [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduction) be kept as is, should it be burninated, or should different tags be made (and if so, what should they be?)?

Comment: Meaning #1 also has [[tag:reducers]], see [Should we reduce the use of \[reducers\]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407897/should-we-reduce-the-use-of-reducers)

Comment: I don't think creating 10 tags for this tag is all that useful.

Comment: @Braiam Me neither, but I think meanings 1, 2, 3, and maybe 5 should at least have their own tags. The rest can be tagged with something else instead of [tag:reduction].

Comment: As a term it's either from complexity theory or from lambda calculus. I think the on-topic Q&A for all questions with [reduction] is Theoretical Computer Science.

Answer (score 3):

(This is not really offering a solution, just commenting on meaning #1, however it’s way too long for a comment.)

Interesting − I’ve always taken reduction to be the meaning 1, and never heard of the word `fold` before. This concept is present in many high-level programming languages under the name `reduce()` (hence the confusion?), and maybe these tags should be synonyms:

- javascript’s [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- python 2’s [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce) (now [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.reduce))
- ruby’s [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
- php’s [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
- java’s [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)
- C++’s [`std::reduce`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)

(called [`Aggregate`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0#definition) in C#)

This concept also has a particular applicability to parallel programming. See for example:

- MPI’s [`MPI_Reduce`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) if you’re reducing across several nodes
- OpenMP’s [`reduction`](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu107.html) clauses

---

For what it’s worth, I *think* there’s a subtle difference, but over which it may not be worth splitting hairs:

- if the operator is not associative, the data structure is necessarily analysed recursively − I would call this a fold
- if the operator is associative, operations may be grouped arbitrarily which is useful e.g. for parallelism or vectorisation − which I would call a reduction

C++ and java seem to agree on this for example, with [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) performing a fold while `std::reduce` and `Stream.reduce` require the function to be associative and stateless, while the other languages effectively perform folds under the name `reduce`. Parallel programming is of course only interested in reductions and not in folds.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize they're not quite the same thing. I do agree that [fold] and [reduction]/[reducers] could still be grouped under one general tag, since there's quite a lot of overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are also tags for a host of other fundamental operators and programming constructs, many of which are at least partially ambiguous because they are already overloaded terms in basic English. For instance, [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addition), [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/migration), [integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration), [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception), [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection)...

Are those tags useful? Debatable. Not to me. But somehow there are 1296 questions which use [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addition). Does *anyone* actually watch [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addition)?

So, OP's premise would seem to imply [burnination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burnination) of all of those tags which are semantically valid, so fundamental/banal as to be simultaneously inevitable from unsophisticated users... and yet almost completely unhelpful to other users in their purpose of search, watches, etc.

I'm not experienced enough in the community to know whether we have a problem with the administrative burden of excessive/ambiguous tags. My guess would be: that's the whole point of tagging instead of hierarchical taxonomy: they're non-exclusive, so having a mediocre tag doesn't block having good ones and so is theoretically not harmful... *as long as it doesn't actively mislead or create conflict or additional work for mods*. It's just a few more bits on the pile, we have a whole bunch of them, and so it's on the user (and their editors) to choose useful tags.

So, while a sophisticated editor would likely never use those tags... they're seemingly not hurtin' anything. Removing them would create a burden of ongoing explanation and maintenance. (And yet, I wouldn't mind seeing it happen.)

---

Adding the [Criteria/Process for Burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination), under which this tag debatably fails the meaningfulness test, and might have trouble with "mean[ing] the same thing in all common contexts", but AFAIK does not fail the most critical test of actually doing harm.

Comment: I don't think we're talking burnination here. These are language-agnostic concepts, they don't have to be accompanied by a language tag to be meaningful.

Comment: I agree. And I'm not arguing that the words are un- _meaningful_. I'm saying that the terms are so general and overloaded by both language and programming concepts as to be almost entirely un-_useful_ as tags. However, I'm still *not* arguing for burnination. Just saying that there are some tags which simply don't add much value, which is unavoidable.